# How use system.tuple in powershell?

Tags: powershell, tuples

Just for curiosity, it's not a 'I must have it', but how declare a tuple using system.tuple class in powershell?

I'm using powershell.exe.config to load framework 4.0 but I'm not able to create a tuple.

Trying this:

```
PS C:\ps1> $a = [System.Tuple``2]::Create( "pino", 34)

Chiamata al metodo non riuscita. [System.Tuple`2] non contiene un metodo denominato 'Create'.
In riga:1 car:31
+ $a = [System.Tuple``2]::Create <<<< ( "pino", 34)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Create:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

sorry for Italian sample...

Thank you for help.

EDIT:

if i try:

```
PS C:\ps1> $a = [System.Tuple]::Create(34,"pino")

Impossibile trovare un overload per "Create" e il numero di argomenti: "2".
In riga:1 car:28
+ $a = [System.Tuple]::Create <<<< (34,"pino")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Did you try `get-member -inputobject $a` to retrieve members along with their definitions?

Comment: @empo: Yes, the create method exist on [system.tuple]::Create with this definition: static System.Tuple[T1,T2] Create[T1, T2](T1 item1, T2 item2) but I'm really stuck hoe use it! Edit: is a static method.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to use that type at the moment. Anyway I've seen in powershell people which works around tuples. See [this](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2007/12/02/another-way-to-create-tuples-in-powershell/) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/11/29/tuples-in-powershell.aspx).

Comment: @empo. thanks but my question is how use system.tuple. Yours links talk about a PoSh function to emulate a tuple object.

Comment: Yes, that's why it was a comment ;-)

Comment: @empo: sorry.. didnt want be rude! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a way

```
PS> $a = New-Object 'Tuple[string,int]'("Jack", 78)
PS> $a

Item1                                             Item2
-----                                             -----
Jack                                              78
```

Another one

```
PS> $dpt = New-Object 'Tuple[string,string,int]'("Cantal", "Aurillac", 15)
PS> $dpt.Item2
Aurillac
```

------EDIT------

**Recall**

to see which CLR you are using, just use `$PSVersionTable`

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4959
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

if you want PowerShell to start using CLR 4.0 you have to put the file `powershell.exe.config` in the folder `$PSHOME` (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0)

powershell.exe.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Result :

```
PS C:\Users\JPB> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
WSManStackVersion              2.0
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.225
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```